# Prevent redraw of highchart when fetching data using ajax call

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I wonder if someone has come across this problem using Highchart. Im using a data dynamically fetch from an API and rendering them to a bar chart.What I want to do is every time an updated data is fetch it would render into the bar chart. Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(function() {
  window.campaign_graph_data = [];
  function getCampaigns() {
    dashboard_data = {
      user_id: window.userId
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: window.apiURL + "tally/api/tally/all",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(dashboard_data),
      headers: {
        Authorization: window.currentUser + " " + window.apiKey
      },
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        var api_options;
        if (response.data.length != 0) {
          $(".no-data-dashboard").addClass("hide");
          $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
            api_options =
              '<option id="campaign-' +
              value.id +
              '" value="' +
              value.id +
              '">' +
              value.tally_name +
              "</option>";
            $(".campaign-dropdown").append(api_options);
          });
          $(".campaign-dropdown option:nth-child(2)").val();
          $(".campaign-dropdown option:nth-child(2)").prop("selected", true);
          $(".campaign-dropdown").trigger("change");
          $("#dashboard-btn-graph").addClass("dashboard-button-active");
          $(".show-graph").removeClass("hide");
          $(".campaign-dropdown option:nth-child(1)").remove();
          $(".dashboard-btn").prop("disabled", false);
          $(".campaign-dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
          $(".no-data-dashboard").removeClass("hide");
        }
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }

  getCampaigns();

  $(".select2-dropdown").select2();

  $(document).off("change", ".campaign-dropdown");
  $(document).unbind("change", ".campaign-dropdown");
  $(document).on("change", ".campaign-dropdown", function() {
    selected_campaign = $(this).val();
    getCampaignbyId(selected_campaign);

    window.poll_fetch = setInterval(function() {
      getCampaignbyId(selected_campaign);
    }, 10000);
  });

  function getCampaignbyId(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: window.apiURL + "tally/api/dashboard/campaign/" + id,
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {
        Authorization: window.currentUser + " " + window.apiKey
      },
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        campaign_graph_data = [];
        campaign_graph_legend_name = [];
        campaign_table_data = [];
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
          var inc_value;
          if (value.increase != 0) {
            inc_value =
              '<span style="color:green">(' +
              " + " +
              value.increase +
              " increase )</span>";
          } else {
            inc_value = "";
          }

          response_graph_api_data = {
            name: value.Choice,
            data: [
              {
                y: parseInt(value.current),
                name: value.Choice,
                description: value.Description,
                color: value.option_color,
                increased_value: inc_value
              }
            ]
          };
          response_table_api_data = {
            name: value.Choice,
            color: value.option_color,
            current: value.current,
            increased_value: value.increase,
            percentage: value.percentage,
            previous: value.previous
          };
          campaign_graph_data.push(response_graph_api_data);
          campaign_table_data.push(response_table_api_data);
          campaign_graph_legend_name.push(value.Choice);
          localStorage.setItem(
            "Graph Data",
            JSON.stringify(campaign_graph_data)
          );
          //chart.redraw();
          //chart.series[].setData(campaign_graph_data,true)
        });
        console.log(campaign_graph_data);
        console.log(chart);
        //chart.series[0].name = campaign_graph_legend_name;

        /*if(campaign_graph_data.length == 2){
         chart.setSize(null,200);
        }

        else if(campaign_graph_data.length <= 10){
         chart.setSize(null,400);
        }
        else{
         chart.setSize(null,500);
        }*/
        console.log(campaign_graph_data.length);
        console.log(campaign_table_data);

        $(".chart-legend-items").empty();
        $(".table-graph-items-content").empty();

        $.each(campaign_graph_data, function(key, value) {
          console.log(value);
          api_graph_legend =
            '<li><i class="fa fa-square" style="color:' +
            value.color +
            '"></i>&nbsp;' +
            value.name +
            "</li>";
          console.log(api_graph_legend);
          $(".chart-legend-items").append(api_graph_legend);
        });

        $.each(campaign_table_data, function(key, value) {
          console.log(value);
          api_table_items = "<tr>";
          api_table_items +=
            '<td>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-square" style="color:' +
            value.color +
            '"></i>&nbsp;</td>';
          api_table_items += "<td>" + value.name + "</td>";
          api_table_items +=
            "<td>&nbsp; + &nbsp;" + value.increased_value + "</td>";
          api_table_items += "<td>" + value.current + "</td>";
          api_table_items += "<td>" + value.percentage + "</td>";
          api_table_items += "</tr>";
          $(".table-graph-items-content").append(api_table_items);
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: "chart-container",
            type: "bar"
          },
          title: {
            text: null
          },
          xAxis: {
            title: {
              text: "Choices"
            },
            type: "category"
          },
          yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1,
            title: {
              text: "Number of Votes"
            }
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              //pointWidth: 20,
            }
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            labelFormatter: function() {
              return this.name;
            }
          },
          series: campaign_graph_data,
          credits: false,
          tooltip: {
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0)",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)",
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return (
                " " +
                '<span style="color:white">Description: ' +
                this.point.description +
                "</span><br />" +
                '<span style="color:white">Current: ' +
                this.point.y +
                "</span><br />" +
                this.point.increased_value
              );
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This works fine but not what I am after because the chart redraws always. I've looked into using the `setData()` function available but i think it requires you to know the charts exact index but produces the result I want if I convert my data to a single series. So as for my question, Is there any way to use the highcharts set data function for multiple series/points?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. If you wish the new data to appear the chart must be redrawn. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @KamilKulig I want to prevent the redraw animation to make it seem that the chart gets updated real time through polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was able to manipulate it by placing a dummy data placeholder. using this code would prevent the chart from doing the redraw animation and instead just update the data.

```js
$(document).on('change','.campaign-dropdown', function(){
  selected_campaign = $(this).val();
  getGraphDashboardBase(selected_campaign);

 });

 function getGraphDashboardBase(id){
  $.ajax({
   url:  window.apiURL + 'tally/api/dashboard/campaign/'+id,
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   headers:{
    Authorization: window.currentUser+' '+window.apiKey
   },
   dataType: 'json',

   success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    
    seriesLength = response.data.length;
    seriesPlaceholdArray = [];
    chartConfig.series = [];
    for( i = 0; i < seriesLength; i++){
     createChart(response.data[i].Choice,[],response.data[i].option_color);
    }
    getCampaignbyId(id);
    window.clearInterval(window.poll_fetch);
    window.poll_fetch = setInterval (function(){
     getCampaignbyId(id);
    },10000);

   }
  });
 }

 function getCampaignbyId(id){
  $.ajax({
   url:  window.apiURL + 'tally/api/dashboard/campaign/'+id,
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   headers:{
    Authorization: window.currentUser+' '+window.apiKey
   },
   dataType: 'json',

   success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    campaign_graph_data = [];
    campaign_graph_legend_name = [];
    campaign_table_data = [];
    response_graph_api_data = [];
    $.each(response.data, function(i,value){
     var inc_value;
     if( value.increase != 0){
      inc_value = '<span style="color:green">('+' + '+value.increase+' increase )</span>';
     }
     else{
      inc_value =''; 
     }

     response_graph_api_data = [{

      y:parseInt(value.current),
      name:value.Choice,
      description:value.Description,
      color:value.option_color,
      increased_value:inc_value 
     }]
     response_table_api_data = {
      name:value.Choice,
      color:value.option_color,
      current:value.current,
      increased_value:value.increase,
      percentage:value.percentage,
      previous:value.previous
     }
     campaign_graph_data.push(response_graph_api_data);
     campaign_table_data.push(response_table_api_data);
     chart.series[i].setData(response_graph_api_data);
     
    });
    //chart.series[0].setData(campaign_graph_data);

    /*marginTop + marginBottom + ((pointWidth * barCount) * (1 + groupPadding + pointPadding));*/
    //pointCount  = chart.series.length;
    var pointCount = chart.series.length;
    chartHeight = marginTop + marginBottom + ((pointWidth * pointCount) *(1 + groupPadding + pointPadding));

    chart.setSize(null,chartHeight);

    

    $('.chart-legend-items').empty();
    $('.table-graph-items-content').empty();

    $.each(campaign_graph_data,function(key,value){
     api_graph_legend ='<li><i class="fa fa-square" style="color:'+value.color+'"></i>&nbsp;'+value.name+'</li>';
     console.log(api_graph_legend);
     $('.chart-legend-items').append(api_graph_legend);
    });

    $.each(campaign_table_data,function(key,value){
     api_table_items = '<tr>';
     api_table_items +='<td>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-square" style="color:'+value.color+'"></i>&nbsp;</td>';
     api_table_items +='<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
     api_table_items +='<td>&nbsp; + &nbsp;'+value.increased_value+'</td>';
     api_table_items +='<td>'+value.current+'</td>';
     api_table_items +='<td>'+value.percentage+'</td>';
     api_table_items +='</tr>';
     $('.table-graph-items-content').append(api_table_items);
    });

    

   }
  });
 }

 var pointWidth = 20;
   var marginTop = 70;
   var marginRight = 10;
   var marginBottom = 50;
   var marginLeft = 100;
   var groupPadding = 0;
   var pointPadding = 0.3;

 var chartConfig = {
  chart: {
   renderTo: 'chart-container',
   type: 'bar',
  },
  title: {
   text: null
  },
  xAxis: {
   title: {
    text: 'Choices'
   },
   type: "category"
  },
  yAxis:{
   tickInterval:1,
   title:{
    text: 'Number of Votes'
   }
  },
  legend:{
   enabled:true,
   symbolRadius:0
  },
  plotOptions:{
   bar:{
    grouping:false,
    pointPadding:pointPadding,
    groupPadding:groupPadding,
    pointWidth:pointWidth

   },
  },
  credits:false,
  series:[],
  tooltip: {
   borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0)',
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
   useHTML:true,
   formatter: function() {return ' ' +
   '<span style="color:white">Description: '+ this.point.description + '</span><br />' +
   '<span style="color:white">Current: ' + this.point.y + '</span><br />'+
   this.point.increased_value;

  }
 }
}

function createChart(name,data,color){ 
 
 tempGraphArray = {
  name:name,
  data:data,
  color:color
 }

 chartConfig.series.push(tempGraphArray);
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartConfig);
 
}
```